# Получить разницу между датами в секундах

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

Задача в том, чтобы получить значение в секундах, избежав большое количество подсчетов.

Можно ли так, получить timestamp начальной даты и текущей, высчитать разницу и эту разницу перевести в число?

Реализовал это так, но не устраивает обилие операций для подсчета секунд.

```
// получим первый день года и текущий
$targetTime = new DateTime(date('Y') . '-01-01 00:00:00');
$currentTime = new DateTime;

// найдем разницу
$difference = $targetTime->diff($currentTime);

// переведем это в секунды
$seconds = $difference->days * 24 * 60 * 60;

// добавим дни в последнем месяце
$seconds = $seconds + ($difference->d * 24 * 60 * 60) + ($difference->m * 60 * 60) + $difference->s;
```

Comment: В целом всё нормально в вашем примере.

Comment: Задачу решает, но слишком много умножения. Этот скрипт будет отрабатываться при каждом обновлении страницы, поэтому хочется уменьшить количество операций

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strtotime — Преобразует текстовое представление даты на английском языке в метку времени Unix

```
$targetTime = strtotime(date('Y') . '-01-01 00:00:00');
$currentTime = strtotime("now");

echo $currentTime-$targetTime;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php

```
<?php

$a = strtotime ('now');
$b = strtotime ('-60 seconds);

echo ($a - $b);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo date('U')-strtotime('10.12.2018');
```